# To add a Java script file in a customize feature in drupal

Tags: drupal, open-atrium

i have create a customize feature in open atrium. now i have to implement the a javascript file like mindmap in that customise feature. how can this possible to add in the open atrium feature.

i have completed the feature using the book module of the open atrium. Now i have to change only the text area in to mindmap.how can it implemented in the feature.plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the open atrium custom feature and want add a js file then you can follow the build a feature link https://community.openatrium.com/documentation-en/node/449
and then read the drupal_add_js function in the link http://drupal.org/node/304255.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use drupal_add_js() in a custom module or theme depending on what you are making. If it is a one off site just add it to your theme. If youre trying to fix the moduel add it directly to the upstream module. If youre augmenting the module for your own purposes add it to a new helper module so that you can upgrade that module in the future without concerns of losig your work.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6

Comment: hi michael do you help me to add the js file in ny custom file